# Set up Cloudtrail s3 Bucket with proper Policy

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to get Cloudtrail on the road and want to set up a Cloudtrail s3bucket. but the Policy does not complete. Here is my code:

```
CloudtrailBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DeletionPolicy: Delete
  Description: Stores all Trails for this account
  Properties:
  AccessControl: BucketOwnerFullControl
  BucketName: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}-invoice-cloudtrail"
  LifecycleConfiguration:
    Rules:
    - Id: GlacierRule
      Prefix: glacier
      Status: Enabled
      ExpirationInDays: '365'
      Transitions:
        - TransitionInDays: '1'
          StorageClass: Glacier
  BucketEncryption:
    ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
      - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
          SSEAlgorithm: AES256
  Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: !Sub '${EnvironmentName} ${Project}-CloudtrailBucket'
  VersioningConfiguration:
    Status: Suspended
```

and this is the Policy I want to use:

```
CloudtrailBucketPolicy:
 Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
 Properties:
  Bucket: !Ref CloudtrailBucket
  PolicyDocument:
    Statement:
    - Sid: AWSCloudTrailAclCheck
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
      Action:
        - s3:GetBucket*
      Resource:
       - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${AWS::AccountId}-invoice-cloudtrail/*"
    - Sid: AWSCloudTrailWrite
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
      Action: s3:PutObject
      Resource:
         - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${AWS::AccountId}-invoice-cloudtrail/*"
      Condition:
        StringEquals:
          s3:x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control
```

I really dont know what might wrong. the error message is the following:

```
Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy; Request ID: 7A458D04A5765AC6; S3 Extended Request ID: EYn2is5Oph1+pnZ0u+zEH067fWwD0fyq1+MRGRxJ1qT3WK+e1LFjhhE9fTLOFiBnhSzbItfdrz0=)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to change your policy to match the following:

```yaml
CloudtrailBucketPolicy:
 Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
 Properties:
  Bucket: !Ref CloudtrailBucket
  PolicyDocument:
    Statement:
    - Sid: AWSCloudTrailAclCheck
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
      Action:
        - s3:GetBucketAcl
      Resource:
       - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${AWS::AccountId}-invoice-cloudtrail"
    - Sid: AWSCloudTrailWrite
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
      Action: s3:PutObject
      Resource:
         - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${AWS::AccountId}-invoice-cloudtrail/*"
      Condition:
        StringEquals:
          s3:x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control
```

The reasoning is that `s3:GetBucket*` expands to `s3:GetBucketAcl`, `s3:GetBucketCORS`, etc ([all here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html)), all of these expecting a bucket as resource, and you have provided many objects on your original policy.
So I've changed the resource (removed `/*`) and also cleaned the policy a bit, since CloudTrail should required only `s3:GetBucketAcl`.